# Javascript alternative to CSS selectors

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using jQuery, how would I go about changing the style of the `<span>` element, when the image is hovered in each post?

Here is an example of the HTML structure:

```
<img src="#" class="postone">

<div class="description">
    <p><span class="postone"> text </span> other text </p>
</div>


<img src="#" class="posttwo">

<div class="description">
    <p><span class="posttwo"> text </span> other text </p>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery I have already:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $("img").hover( function(){

        var className = $("this").attr('class');
        $("span" + className).css("color", "#fff");

    });

});
```

Comment: You would use CSS, probably. Why don’t you want to?

Comment: `$("span" + className)` should be `$("span." + className)`

Comment: … and `$("this")` should be `$(this)`, yes, but really – use CSS.

Comment: Last time I checked, [browser support for :hover](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/%3Ahover) is pretty good. Do you need to support IE6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `this` is a keyword, not a string, so the quotes should be removed.

   ```
   var className = $(this).attr('class');
   ```
2. You're missing a period in your selector. The `className` value does not contain this period since the `class` attribute contains class names, not class selectors, so you will have to put it in the selector string yourself.

   ```
   $("span." + className).css("color", "#fff");
   ```

With that said, I *really* don't see why you couldn't do this with CSS:

```css
img:hover + .description span {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how you would do it with css - so I will be using that instead of the javascript!

Comment: Clock, how would I do it the other way round? When you hover over the `<span>`,  the images border changes colour? -- I'm pretty sure you would just javascript

Comment: @SAMTHEMAN999: Hmm yeah, you wouldn't be able to target it using CSS then.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var className;
    $("img").hover(function() {
        className = $(this).attr('class');  
        $("span." + className).css("color", "#fff");
    }, function() {
        className = $(this).attr('class');
        $("span." + className).css("color", "#000");
    });
});
```

You are missing a `.` in your class selector, and you also need to remove the double quotes from `$(this)`. Add a mouseout function also in your code.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6HtE/)

Comment: It is best to explain what you changed and *why*, rather than have OP hunt for the changes and guess as to why they work.

Comment: @ajp15243, I have updated my answer with explanation. Thanks.